# Recursively returning a function call - theory re return statement

Tags: javascript, recursion

In the following recursive function, notice how we must use `return` before `printArr`. If we do not use `return`, and just do `printArr(num-1, [...arr, num]`, the return value of the recursive function is `undefined`.

I've searched on Google and StackOverflow for an explanation for this specific topic, but could not find an answer. Can someone please explain why we need to use `return` when making a recursive call to the function, or even direct me to a StackOverflow question or blog post that I may have missed.

I think it may have something to do with the call stack, but conceptually it's just hard for me to wrap my head around it.

```
const printArr = (num, arr) => {
  if (!num)
    return arr

  return printArr(num - 1, [...arr, num])
}

const printArr2 = (num, arr) => {
  if (!num)
    return arr

  printArr(num - 1, [...arr, num])
}

// [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(printArr(10, [])) 

// undefined
console.log(printArr2(10, []))
```

Comment: It's pretty clear. A function that doesn't explicitly return a value, returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, if you do not execute a `return` statement in a function, then the return value will be `undefined`.

Since you want to return a value, you need a `return` statement.

If the condition is met, then you have the value you want to return, so you `return` that.

If the condition is not met, then you need to recursively call the function and `return` the result of that.